# JavaFX GUI keeps freezing when executing loop

Tags: selenium, javafx

I have literally read everywhere. I cannot solve this.

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    public Label myTimes;
    @FXML
    private TextField username;
    @FXML
    private TextField password;
    @FXML
    private TextField totalTimes;
    public void times (ActionEvent event) {
        String usernameVar = username.getText();
        String passwordVar = password.getText();
        String times = totalTimes.getText();
        main Main = new main();
        Main.booster(usernameVar, passwordVar, Integer.parseInt(times));
        myTimes.setText("Completed: " + Integer.toString(Main.timess));

    }
```

The booster method is opening selenium and performing tasks on the web. But as it does this, the GUI freezes until the task is done. I have tried using tasks and threads but no luck (I don't really know how to use them). Could anyone please give me a solution?

Comment: The solution is to use tasks and threads. If that's not working, it's because you haven't done it correctly. You should post your attempt to do that and explain in what way it
 doesn't work.

Comment: did you used threads and tasks inner your method  **booster** or u called your method from your controller using a thread?

Comment: I used tasks and after hours I finally got it to work.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two options in Java:

1. Using a `Thread`

   Documentation: [Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)
2. Using a `Task` (kind of `Runnable Class`)

   Documentation: [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html)

   Little example: [Task with ProgressBar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45867364/8087490)

I use normaly a `Task` but that's just a matter of taste

P.S.: The code in the thread or task runs in the background and your other code continues normal

Comment: But you still need a thread if you use a task, of course.

Comment: Thats right :) I updated my answer... In your case I suggest you to try the example link... If you have problems you can right me again

Comment: But `Task` doesn't extend `Thread`.

Comment: @Developer66 Task is not a kind of thread.Task is abstract class extends FutureTask .It is like a Runnable class.